# How can I write a pojo for this complex json and deserialize the the json request?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I need to parse this json structure in java.

```
{
"collection": "collectionname",
"field_rules": [{
    "fieldname": "fieldname1",
    "modules":

        [{
        "module": "module1",
        "options": {
            "key1": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        }
    }, {
        "module": "module2"
    }, {
        "module": "module3"
    }, {
        "module": "module5"
    }]
}, {
    "fieldname": "fieldname2",
    "modules":

        [{
        "module": "module6",

        "options": {
            "keytype": [{
                "key1": "val1"
            }, {
                "key2": "val2"
            }],
            "key3": "val3"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "fieldname": "fieldname3",
    "modules":

        [{
        "module": "module7",
        "options": {
            "key1": "val1"
        }
    }, {
        "module": "module8",
        "options": {
            "key1": "val1"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "fieldname": "fieldname4",
    "modules": [{
        "module": "module9",
        "options": {
            "key1": ["val1", "val2"],
            "key2": "val1",
            "key3": "val1"
        }

    }]
}]
```

}

I have written some pojo classes that let me parse the json till modules like this (Just writing the fields only here...).

```
Class Command { 

 String collection;
 List<FieldRules> field_rules;
 }

Class FieldRules { 
String fieldname;
List<Module> modules;
}

Class Modules {
String module;
Options options; 

}
```

Now I have need a pojo class for Options. As you can see options can be any of 3-4 structures as in the example. How can I create  a pojo for Options class?  Or could there be any other options other than using the pojo classes for deserializing such complex json structure ? Thanks in advance!!!

I tried using 4 custom classes that extends from a base class Options and when I try to access them like this :   commandJson.getField_rules().get(1).getModule().get(0).getOptions().getOptionType I get a null value. How can I solve this?

Comment: You start by writing code then coming back with a specific question other than "How do I do this"

Comment: i have edited the question...